# how to run cmake tests in a single command instead of executing test program per test

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, xctest

I am currently porting a larger project from make to cmake. Everthing works fine but I have a issue/problem running a google test application. I have one test program containing about 5500 tests (a lot of parameterized tests). I use gtest_discover_tests to register all tests. The issue seems to be that ctest exectutes the test program for each test using --gtest_filter=<test_name>. The problem is that my app needs a view seconds to initialize. Normally the tests needs about 10 min to execute all tests, with ctest it needs about 40 min.

Is there any way to tell cmake/ctest to run the binary once using all tests?

EDIT:

To make it a bit clear how it works

1. test start
2. framework init (~2 seconds)
3. run **one** test
4. framework shutdown
5. back to one

What I want

1. test start
2. framework init (~2 seconds)
3. run **ALL** tests
4. framework shutdown

Comment: Instead of having one huge test executable compile your tests into multiple smaller test executables. You can keep your current folder structure and even reuse your current main.cpp in multiple executables.

Comment: this does not solve the problem of initializing the framework each time

Comment: What does you CMake file look like? you should be able to say something like `add_test(NAME <TEST_CASE_NAME> COMAND <TEST_CASE>)`. Then run make test should only configure the framework once. If I recall correctly

Comment: "The issue seems to be that ctest exectutes the test program for each test using --gtest_filter=<test_name>" - not seems, this is exactly what [gtest_discover_tests](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html#command:gtest_discover_tests) does. Just don't use it if you don't want to run the test binary multiple times. Instead register one CTest test per one googletest test binary.

Comment: Create a new `target` with all your test sources with no main and link in `gtest` & `gtest_main` and you can run that executable and it will run all tests found in the source files. And you can then pass `--gtest_filter=*xyz*` if you wish. This just avoids ctest